# How to save image link after rotation with html and js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some html and js code that loads an image from a url and allows you to rotate it. I want to be able to save the image after it has been rotated, preferably with a new url. I would also prefer to use html and js to do it if possible, but I'm open to jquery or w/e else you have in mind since I have no idea how to do this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #photoimg {
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
            #photo {
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="url" name="imglink" id="imglink"  placeholder="Insert image URL here" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Show Image" id="btn1"/>
    </form>
        <div id="photo"></div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
                document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img id="photoimg" src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image"/>';
                //Get larger edge
                var largerPhotoDimension = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetWidth , 2) + Math.pow(document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetHeight ,2) );
                var marginVert = (largerPhotoDimension - document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetHeight)/2;
                var marginHorz = (largerPhotoDimension - document.getElementById('photoimg').offsetWidth)/2;
                //Adjust container to fix image rotated 90deg
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginRight =  marginHorz;
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginLeft =  marginHorz;
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginBottom = marginVert;  
                document.getElementById('photo').style.marginTop = marginVert;                  
            });
        </script>
        <button id="button">rotate</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
            var curr_value = document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform;
            var new_value = "rotate(90deg)";
            if(curr_value !== ""){
                var new_rotate = parseInt(curr_value.replace("rotate(","").replace(")","")) + 90;
                new_value = "rotate(" + new_rotate + "deg)";
            }
            document.getElementById('photoimg').style.transform = new_value;
        };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding regarding what your code really does - It doesn't touch the image itself, it rather changes how it is displayed. If your goal is to make the result saveable (like a photo editor), you should have a look at using a canvas instead (although it's a bit more advanced).

Comment: You should have posted this as an answer, I would have chosen it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot save an image using javascript.
you can use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) a php plugin or another server side script ot another php addon.

```
<?php 
    function rotateImage($imagePath, $angle, $color) {
        $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
        $imagick->rotateimage($color, $angle);
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        echo $imagick->getImageBlob(); 
    } 
?>
```

here is the documentation for it:
http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.rotateimage.php

Comment: How compatible would this method be? That is, does it work on all browsers? I would be happy with anything above IE8. I'm trying to apply the rules of progressive enhancement.

Comment: yes. its a server side script. as long as it is installed on the server it will work on all bowsers.

Comment: This option, as well as using canvas, are both good ideas I am going to look into. Thanks!